# search for string in column names and retrieve corresponding value for each row

Tags: r, string, dataframe, subset

I have a df like this:

```
id <- c("defoo","ghfoo","abfoo")
abc <- c(.3,.1,.4)
ghi <- c(.4,.2,.2)
abc_dif <- c(.4,.3,.8)
def_dif <- c(.5,.7,.6)
ghi_dif <- c(.2,.1,.9)
df <- data.frame(id,abc,ghi,abc_dif,def_dif,ghi_dif)
```

I want to look for columns whose names contain the first two characters of the value in the id row and also include "dif," and create a new column containing the corresponding values in those columns for each row.

In this sample data, the new column would be

```
df$result <- c(.5,.1,.8)
```

My numerous attempts involved various versions of sapply and apply, like the following attempt to simply get the column index:

```
df$result <- apply(substr(df[,which(colnames(df)=="id")],1,2),1,function(x) grep(x,colnames(df[which(grepl("dif",colnames(df),fixed=TRUE))]),fixed = TRUE))
```

This gives the error:

> ```
> "Error in apply(substr(df[, which(colnames(df) == "id")], 1, 2), 1, function(x) grep(x,  : 
>   dim(X) must have a positive length"
> ```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a `row/column` index to get the values

```
df$result <- df[4:6][cbind(1:nrow(df), match( substr(df$id, 1, 2),
                substr(names(df)[4:6], 1, 2)))]

df$result
#[1] 0.5 0.1 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(k,v, -id:-ghi) %>% 
  filter(str_sub(id,1,2) == str_sub(k,1,2)) %>% 
  select(1,result=v) %>% 
  left_join(df, .)
     id abc ghi abc_dif def_dif ghi_dif result
1 defoo 0.3 0.4     0.4     0.5     0.2 0.5
2 ghfoo 0.1 0.2     0.3     0.7     0.1 0.1
3 abfoo 0.4 0.2     0.8     0.6     0.9 0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the `df$id` and then for each one, select the relevant cell in `df`:

```
df$result <- sapply(df$id, function(x) df[df$id == x,
                                          grepl(paste0(substring(x,1,2),".*dif"), names(df))])

df$result
#[1] 0.5 0.1 0.8
```